# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION code=EXC_I386_INVOP on Fibonacci count function

Tags: swift4

I'm very newbie with Swift (and non-dynamic typed languages), and trying to make a function which makes an array of the first 100 Fibonacci numbers.

Here is it:

```
func buildFibonacci(){
    var numbers: [Int64] = [0,1]
    for x in (2...99) {    
        numbers.append(numbers[x-1] + numbers[x-2])
    }
    print(numbers)
}

buildFibonacci()
```

But when I run it, on 93-th iteration I get an error:

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

As far as I understand, it is being raised on the sum operation.

My guess that this is something about size of Int so I changed it into Int64, but it looks like the problem was in something else. I use swift 4.1, if it is important. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is right, it's an overflow exception, the number becomes too high to be represented in 64 bit. On 64 bit machines `Int` is `Int64` anyway so the type change makes no difference.

A solution is to use `NSDecimalNumber` which is not restricted to 64 bit and provides basic arithmetic methods.

```
func buildFibonacci(){
    var numbers: [NSDecimalNumber] = [.zero, .one]
    for x in 2...99 {
        numbers.append(numbers[x-1].adding(numbers[x-2]))
    }
    print(numbers)
}

buildFibonacci()
```